# python convert ibis (Impala) table into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, join, type-conversion, ibis

Does anybody know how to convert ibis (Impala) table (`<class 'ibis.expr.types.TableExpr'>`) into pandas dataframe?

Actually I want to merge (join) ibis table & pandas dataframe.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fetch the table into a data frame using execute:

```
df1 = table.limit(None).execute()
```

Then merge as normal:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2])
```